# #Define Variables Scope

Tags: c, scope, c-preprocessor

I am wondering if there is a way to define a global variable that has the name of a specific instance from my main function? I have to access an array by bit values so to do that I need to type:

```
state.reg[ 4 * mc_binary[ 18 ] + 2 * mc_binary[ 17 ] + 1 * mc_binary[ 16 ] ]
```

Can I have:

```
#define state.reg[ 4 * mc_binary[ 18 ] + 2 * mc_binary[ 17 ] + 1 * mc_binary[ 16 ] ] registerA
```

where `state` is my instance of a `stateType` struct that is used in my main function?

Comment: So you tried it and what happened?  Your team mates couldn't understand the code anymore?

Comment: I don't have team mates. I'm not trying to get it to work, I'm done with the program but looking back on it I was wondering if this was possible OR A FUNCTIONALLY EQUIVALENT method.

Comment: If you think the line is too long, split it across multiple lines instead of removing the semantically correct document formatting.

Comment: Please stop editing my post. You can't see the second part of the define statement. I get that it looks prettier but please stop.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would recommend:

```
#define BIT_INDEX3(bit2, bit1, bit0) \
    (4 * (bit2) + 2 * (bit1) + (bit0))

// use in code:
    state.reg[ BIT_INDEX3(mc_binary[18], mc_binary[17], mc_binary[16]) ]
```

You don't want to get *too* tricky, but if you will often be pulling from the same array (as you did here) you could make another define for that:

```
#define BIT_INDEX_ARRAY3(a, i2, i1, i0) \
    BIT_INDEX3((a)[i2], (a)[i1], (a)[i0])


// use in code:
state.reg[ BIT_INDEX_ARRAY3(mc_binary, 18, 17, 16) ]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm learning the strength of macro definitions and other pre-processors from working with OpenCL. Just trying to experiment with their potential. Thanks again for the answer!